# Laravel 5 | Pagination Issue on setting ID field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-pagination

I Use laravel "paginate()" function to create pagination.

I set the Id field of the record table with "$i++".

But each page starts with 1, 2, 3...

How could i set Id as continue of previous page.

Actually my item table id is not properly, thats why i use "$i++" to create Id.

My Controller:

```
 public function show()
   {
    $items = \Auth::user()->Items()->paginate(5);
    return view('cart.admin.show',compact('items'));
   }
```

My View:

```
  <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
        {!! $items->render() !!}
  </div>
```

What is the Solution for this issue...?

Comment: Add your full code, coz I am unable to understand your problem, + can you clean your database?

Comment: I set paginate(5), so I get 5 item in each page,

in first page i get item id as 1,2,3,4,5....

in second page also i get item id as 1,2,3,4,5....

Buz im not using item id, im using manually created ID...

So its refreshed on every page....

and possibilities for creating continues number as ID...?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can create a [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers) function  in **App/Http/Helpers/helper.php**

```
function serial_number_pagination($current_page, $per_page, $i){
    return (($current_page * $per_page) + $i)-5;
}
```

And call the helper function in your blade file like (in place of displacing $i value),

```
<td>{{ serial_number_pagination($items->currentPage(), $items->perPage(), $i) }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

At blade page, use this before foreach loop:

```
     $sn_count = (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 1) ? (($_GET['page']-1) * 5)+1 : 1;
```